# Flask Blueprint can't find static folder

Tags: python, flask

I've set up a Blueprint in my Flask application, but I can't seem to get my static folder to work. I keep getting 404 errors when it tries to reach them:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2014 15:14:20] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2014 15:14:20] "GET /static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The css one also appends static twice. The JS has the correct /static but doesn't seem to work. Right now, my static folder is in the blueprint root path (`app/dashboard`). I tried putting it into `app/static` but I get the same exact errors.

I have the following set up:

`app/dashboard/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
dashboard = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
from application.dashboard import controllers
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
# Blueprints      
from flask import Blueprint
from application.dashboard import dashboard
app.register_blueprint(dashboard)
```

In `app/templates/layout.html`, I have a line that references two static files as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('dashboard.static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ url_for('dashboard.static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

My `app/dashboard/static` directory:

```
$ tree application/dashboard/static/
application/dashboard/static/
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   └── bootstrap.min.css
├── fonts
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
└── js
    ├── bootstrap.js
    └── bootstrap.min.js
```

Any idea what is going on here? How can I structure my Blueprint properly? I've followed the instructions on the Flask documentation and I get this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look like you have issue with two same routes for application and blueprint. See my [another answer part 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047604/880326).

Your application route `/static/<path:path>` to `.static` endpoint.

Your blueprint route `/static/<path:path>` to `dashboard.static` endpoint, because you do not have `url_prefix` when register blueprint and have `/static` - static folder prefix.

So you can use one of next solutions:

1. use only application static folder.
2. set `url_prefix` when register blueprint.
3. use another static folder prefix for blueprint.
4. disable application static folder `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)`.
5. use [hacks with static endpoint descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19179524/880326).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what the solution is. Is it possible not set a url prefix, but have the static folder go to `dashboard/static`?

Comment: It seems like whatever I add, it doesn't take effect on the Blueprint. It only takes effect if I add it to app. Why is that?

Comment: If you want avoid application static folder route usage, you should disable it: `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)`. Please see details of `url_prefix` or use `url_for('dashboard.static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')` to get real link. Problem because you have two endpoins with same route - one always not work.

Comment: The trick was to just set the static_folder on app to None. Even though I point directly to the route, it does not work. Any idea why? I already did use the proper url_for.

Comment: As I said you has two endpoins one for app `.static` and one for blueprint `dashboard.static`. This two endpoints have same route `/static/<path:path>`. So when you make `url_for('.static', filename='test.css')` or `url_for('dashboard.static', filename='test.css')` it will return `/static/test.css`. When you do request then flask route system get path `/static/test.css` and iterate for each route with priority, when it found first (app endpoint in your case) endpoint which satisfy route this endpoint will be returned and called dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add URL prefix for your blueprint, like so

```
app.register_blueprint(dashboard, url_prefix='/dashboard')
```

Comment: I do not want all dashboard to have a /dashboard prefix. Is that still possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution was to go to the `__init__.py` file for the Blueprint, then add `static_folder="static"` inside the statement defining the blueprint:

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__ ,static_folder = "static")

from . import routes
```

Since the `app` is actually running as the `Blueprint`, `main` here, this tells it to look for the static folder inside the main package.  It doesn't work if you add this to the `__init__.py` script for the app (ask me how I know this...)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use nginx? It's faster in terms of performance and you don't have to write code to serve up static content.

Comment: I'll be using a web server for production. I am testing locally for now.

Comment: Sure, but nginx is easy to run locally and less complicated than coding into flask a set of blueprints. Also it will help ensure what you develop against is tested before you launch it into your prod environment.

Comment: Good advice, but it's like answering "I'm having trouble implementing a linear sort method for a list class. Am I making a syntax error somewhere?" with "Why not use a RB-tree? It's not too hard, and it's consistently `O(logn)`."